# How to prevent a number from being rounded down Python Tkinter

Tags: python, variables, indexing, tkinter, text-widget

I am working on a program that gets the users index position when they are typing in a Text Widget in Tkinter and saves it into a variable. But when ever the index is 1.20 it ends up turning into 1.2 Is there a way to make sure the variable with the index 1.20 in it will stay 1.20?

I have tried using float(). But that did not seem to work.

Any ideas?

And thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `1.20` rather than `1.2`, given that `1.20 == 1.2`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because when using a Tkinter text widget 1.20 stands for a position (First row 20th column). While 1.2 is the first row second column.

Comment: Why not save the two halves separately, e.g. `row, col = map(int, val.split("."))`? Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would like to provide a minimal example but that would be very hard to because the variables start off a string values so it does not round them down. Then I will change it to floats and strings through out the code. i am sorry. I will try out what you said.

Comment: I don't know `tkinter` but it sounds like you want to store the value as text, not a number.

Comment: @GP89 No I want the number for the program I am working on because it is a spell checker.

Comment: you will need to use two numbers, like @jonrsharpe suggested. you can't use a float to represent 1 and 20 at the same time (and differentiate it from 1 and 2)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: don't ever treat the index as a number, because it is not a number. It is a string that happens to look like a number. If you have code that is rounding the value (or truncating trailing zeros), somewhere you're treating it as a number.

Comment: But I need it to refer to it later. So I can add a tag to the position.

Comment: @0Cool: it doesn't matter. It's not a number, it's a string. You can save the string and refer to it later, that is unrelated to how you treat the value. You simply can't use it as a number. You can use it as a string, or you can split it into two numbers, but you can't treat the index as a whole as a floating point number.